# rror sending: timeout expired while executing transaction at HLFConnection.invokeChainCode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

i want to create more than 10000 assets. When i created assets in many requests like 5 requests of 2000 it succeeds to make assets and if i created 15000 assets and when i retrieved it through assetRegistory.getAll() it only returns 10000 assets not more than 10000. How do i solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried changing value of CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE in docker-compose.yml

Comment: see answer in https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4597

Comment: @david_k kindly refer me a way to increase limit? i go through mentioned link but not able to increase limit?

Comment: @Harshit there in no CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE in docker-compose.yml can someone suggest solution?

Comment: @david_k can you please suggest me a perfect framework for my use case. I have to make distributed ledger of shares of different companies. there may be 5000 companies and there another participant is investor. There may b many investors. Each company can have max of 6m shares which can be sale purchased by investors.?

Comment: @AhmadRaza Hi, Did you resolve this issue? Could you please tell me. I'm also stuck with this error..